# App Visor de PDF Ios en Xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode, app

Pues mi problema es el siguiente. Tengo toda la app realizada con dos Viewcontroller. EL problema es que toda la app se desarrolla bien, menos al mostrar la celda de Pdf en la segunda pantalla que no aparece nada. ¿Qué me puede faltar? Este es el código del segundo ViewController donde tengo puesta una vista web desde el primero, y enlazado por un Segue:
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet var VistaWebPdf: WKWebView!

var nombrePdfRecibido: String?

var vistaWebPdf: WKWebView!

override func loadView() {
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    VistaWebPdf = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    VistaWebPdf.uiDelegate = self
    view = VistaWebPdf

    var vistaWebPdf: WKWebView!

    var nombrePdfRecibido:String?
    func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        mostrarPdf()

}

    }

    func mostrarPdf(){

//1 Dirección del archivo PDF
    let nombrePdfRecibido = "PDF"
    let direccionPdf = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: nombrePdfRecibido, ofType: "Pdf", inDirectory: "PDF")!)
```

//2 Transformar archivo PDF a Data

```
    let datosPdf = try? Data(contentsOf: direccionPdf )
```

//3 Mostrar Datos en la Vista Web

VistaWebPdf.load(datosPdf!, mimeType: "application/pdf", characterEncodingName: "utf-8", baseURL: direccionPdf)

```
 }
```

}

POSTERIORMENTE, PONGO EL CÓDIGO DEL VIEWCONTROLLER 1 unido al Navigation Controller:
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

```
var contenidoCeldas = ["PDF1","PDF2","PDF3","PDF4","PDF5","PDF6","PDF7","PDF8"]
@IBOutlet var tabla: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tabla.dataSource = self
    tabla.delegate = self

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return contenidoCeldas.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    print(indexPath.section)

    let celda = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier:"CellPDF")
    celda.textLabel?.text = contenidoCeldas[indexPath.row]

    return celda
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    _ = indexPath.row
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Pantalla_2Segue"){

    }
    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Pantalla_2Segue" {

        let iPdfSeleccionadoRecibido = sender as! NSIndexPath

        let idx = iPdfSeleccionadoRecibido.row
        func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
            if segue.identifier == "Pantalla_2Segue" {
                let idPdfSeleccionadoRecibido = sender as! NSIndexPath
                let idx = idPdfSeleccionadoRecibido.row

                let objPantalla2:ViewController2 = segue.destination as! ViewController2 


    objPantalla2.nombrePdfRecibido = contenidoCeldas[idx]
            }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaria utilizar PDFKit, es una libreria nativa de ios muy sencilla de utilizar introducida por Apple en 2017 (watch?v=V-oy8diDApY)

En tu primera vista ejecuta el segue en el hilo principal de tu programa

Primera vista

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Pantalla_2Segue", sender: nil)
        })
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == self.mySegue {
            let destination:SegundoView = segue.destination as! SegundoView
            destination.urlDePdf = "url_de_pdf"
        }
}
```

Segunda vista

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cell_id, for: indexPath) as! MiCustomCell

        let pdfView = PDFView()
        pdfView.frame = cell.frame
        cell.addSubview(pdfView)
        if let document = PDFDocument(url: URL(string: urlDePdf) ?? URL(string:"")!) {
                pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
                pdfView.autoScales = true
                pdfView.document = document
        }

        return cell

}
```